# Modeling RESTful resources correctly for forbidden access

Tags: rest

I've got multiple routes:

```
/projects
/projects/{id}
/countries?project={id}
/categories?project={id}
```

And I've got a doubt that this is done correctly and want a second opinion on it.

- `project` parameter is a must.
- Users are given access to both `/countries` and `/categories` resources based on `project`
- If someone doesn't have access to it, they now get 403

This feels dodgy because I understand that in RESTful world user is granted access based on resource and not by query parameter.

Would it be more appropriate to model this in the following way?

```
/projects
/projects/{id}
/projects/{id}/countries
/projects/{id}/categories
```

Comment: Do _country_ and _category_ resources depend on a _project_  resource to exist?

Comment: @cassiomolin in this context - yes. `/countries` as a resource wouldn't make sense for this business case without a `project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, given that the *country* and *category* resources require a *project* resource to exist, it makes sense to go for the second approach, nesting everything that belongs to a *project* under `/projects/{id}`:

```
/projects
/projects/{id}
/projects/{id}/countries
/projects/{id}/categories
```

Comment: This will be fare more easy to implement too.